# how to config angular-cli with typescript2.4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using the angular-cli with version 1.2.7, by default, it create new angular apps with typescript 2.3, but now I want to use some feature of typescript 2.4.

I tried to update the `typescript` in package.json, remove all node_modules, and `npm install` again, but this seems not work.

How can I config my project, so that angular-cli can use typescript 2.4 instead?

Comment: Remove your globally installed typescript

Comment: You should probably remove the `package-lock.json` file, and try to install again

Comment: Just FYI, Typescript 2.4 support was added out of the box from angular-cli 1.3.0-rc.0: [release notes](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.3.0-rc.0)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `typescript 2.4` you have to use the 1.3.0 RC version of cli as [support just being added](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/7065) to that. However bare in mind that angular still does not support `typescript 2.4` yet, but it is coming, you can track [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18454) for that matter which is [not stopping you to play with `typescript 2.4` and cli anyway](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/7065#issuecomment-319633691)